# Hey for Sadaqah is it better to give more money to less people or less money to more people?

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity

I was wondering, if in giving Sadaqah it is better to help out more people with a less amount of money or less people with more amounts of money? Which will be more beneficial? Any sources? 
Thanks

Comment: וְהַכֹּל לְפִי רֹב הַמַּעֲשֶׂה. לְפִי מַה שֶּׁאָדָם כּוֹפֵל וּמַתְמִיד בַּעֲשִׂיַּת הַטּוֹב כָּךְ שְׂכָרוֹ מְרֻבֶּה. שֶׁאֵינוֹ דּוֹמֶה הַמְחַלֵּק מֵאָה זְהוּבִים לִצְדָקָה בְּמֵאָה פְּעָמִים, לְנוֹתֵן אוֹתָם בְּפַעַם אַחַת. וְגִרְסַת רַמְבַּ"ם הִיא, וְהַכֹּל לְפִי רֹב הַמַּעֲשֶׂה, אֲבָל לֹא עַל פִּי הַמַּעֲשֶׂה

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the story, so its more about the act then the amount right

Comment: @eli In short, the answer is more to more; but, failing that, less to more, because the objective is to train your hand to give.